# Altcoins to Monero payment buttons for website?

Tags: payment-integration, shapeshift

I tried to implement a monero payment button onto my website via shapeshift and changelly, but neither of them support this payment button widget. Apparently changelly supports XMO (monero original) but not xmr for some odd reason. I want users to be able to pay me with any crypto, but I want to only receive monero which services provide this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [globee](https://globee.com/) and changing afterwards to monero through ShapeShift (you could automate this i think).

Changely has a bad reputation, maybe related to big ASIC miners, and it must be the reason they're on XMO and not XMR.